# need to array display in specific format in php

Tags: php, arrays, formatting

Capture the 'p_data' values into key/pairs and return as table

i try to array display in table format please help me.

```
$diskspace = array (
    'S' => 
        array ('DISK-FREE' => 
                array (
                'name' => 'S',
                'desc' => 'FREE',
                'p_data' => '\'C:\\ %\'=19%;99;95 \'C:\\\'=17B;3;1073741824;0;21476171776 \'D:\\ %\'=63%;99;99 \'D:\\\'=80B;3;1073741824;0;214753800192 \'E:\\ %\'=91%;99;98 \'E:\\\'=58B;3;1073741824;0;64420311040',),
                ),              
     'T' => 
        array ('DISK-FREE' => 
                array ('name' => 'T',
                'desc' => 'FREE',
                'p_data' => '\'C:\\ %\'=11%;99;95 \'C:\\\'=15B;3;1073741824;0;21476171776 \'D:\\ %\'=18%;99;99 \'D:\\\'=62B;3;1073741824;0;214753800192',),
                ),
    'P' => 
        array ('DISK-USED' => 
                array ('name' => 'P',
                'desc' => 'FREE',
                'p_data' => '\'G:\\ %\'=19%;99;95 \'G:\\\'=92B;3;1073741824;0;21476171776',),
                ),
    );
```

HTML Output

```
name, diskname, disk-size, disk-percentage

S,    C:\,      17B,        19%
S,    D:\,      80B,        63%
S,    E:\,      58B,        91%
T,    C:\,      15B,        11%
T,    D:\,      62B,        18%
P,    G:\,      92B,        19%
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified what you wanted to put into the specific attributes as values and I am reluctant to guess it, so I will assume that you have a function which handles a passed p_data and returns the array you need to have.

```
function handlePValue($p_value) {
    //your code here to return the desired value
}

$p_dataValues = array();

foreach ($diskspace as $element) {
    $p_dataValues[] = handlePValue($element["p_data"]);
}
```

Comment: i need to array display in table like HTML output.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear-enough. I refuse to implement your code if you do not care to specify the general description of your input. I do not have time, nor motivation to study your examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to extract All xxB and xx% data and try to display them drom array, make sure you try this for S , T , ... or other data in array

```
function Disk2Array($Name , $array) {
    return $array[$Name]['DISK-FREE']['p_data'];
}

$precent = '/[0-9][0-9]\%/';
$size = '/[0-9][0-9][B]/';

preg_match_all($size , Disk2Array('S' , $diskspace) , $match);
print_r($match);

preg_match_all($precent , Disk2Array('S' , $diskspace) , $match);
print_r($match);
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\xampp\htdocs\array\index.php on line 34

Comment: $diskname = substr(str_pos($arr[0], ":")-1), 1) . ":\\";                    this line

Comment: please help me,i am waiting your reply